# Anaphora resolution using Stanford Coref

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

I have sentences **(Text I)**:

> *Tom is a smart boy. **He** know a lot of thing.*

I want to change **He** in the second sentence to **Tom**, so final sentences will become **(Text II)**:

> *Tom is a smart boy. **Tom** know a lot of thing.*

I've wrote some code, but my ***coref*** object always ***null***.
Besides I have no idea what to do next to get correct result.

```
    String text = "Tom is a smart boy. He know a lot of thing.";
    Annotation document = new Annotation(text);
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, parse, lemma, ner, dcoref");
    StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
    pipeline.annotate(document);

    List<Pair<IntTuple, IntTuple>> coref = document.get(CorefGraphAnnotation.class);
```

I want to know if I'm doing it wrong and what I should do next to get **Text II** from **Text I**.
PS: I'm using Stanford CoreNLP 1.3.0.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe @stompchicken can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<Pair<IntTuple, IntTuple>> coref = document.get(CorefGraphAnnotation.class);
```

This is an old coref output format.

You can change this line to

```
Map<Integer, CorefChain> graph = document.get(CorefChainAnnotation.class);
```

or you can use the `oldCorefFormat` option:

```
props.put("oldCorefFormat", "true");
```

Comment: You need to add `'ner.useSUTime':'false'` in the properties to avoid error