# Anaphora resolution example requested with python-nltk

Tags: python, nltk

I have been looking into the howto for [nltk-drt](http://www.nltk.org/howto/drt.html) and into the module definitions for [nltk.sem.drt](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.sem.html) but I am having a really hard time trying to understand how to achieve basic functionality using these packages.

An example of a task that I would like to achieve is the following: Given the sentence

> Google is one of the largest tech companies. It employees many people.

I would like to be able to write a small function that parses a sentence such as this, and return a sentence such as

> Google is one of the largest tech companies. Google employees many people.

A more realistic test case can be something like

> Tom, Dick and Harry were invited to her party, but declined. This made Sherry angry.

being resolved to

> Tom, Dick and Harry were invited to Sherry party, but declined. This made Sherry angry.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't think DRT (Discourse Representation Theory) deals with [anaphora resolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaphora_(linguistics)#Nomenclature_and_examples), like what you wanted. It deals with representing the meaning of a sentence in formal logic.

Also, there is a name for your "more realistic test case", which is called "[cataphora](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cataphora)".

Anaphora resolution is difficult, but you can try [Stanford DCoref](http://www-nlp.stanford.edu/software/dcoref.shtml)

And see some examples here: [Anaphora resolution using Stanford Coref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768760/anaphora-resolution-using-stanford-coref)

Comment: Thank you so much. While this doesn't solve my problem completely (the syntax of Stanford DCoref seems alien to me, so the solution is going to be hard for me), it gives me a place to start! Also, sorry can't upvote, because not enough points.